# Creating a Linux VM on Azure without a public ip address

Tags: dns, azure

I want to create a linux VM on Azure that sits behind an internet facing load balancer, and it does not need to have a public ip address of its own. Is there a way to do this?
I tried this but the public IP address is always created.

Edit : the VM deploy is in ARM mode

Comment: The VM deploy in ASM or ARM?

Comment: ARM, updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this? I tried this but the public IP address is
>   always created.

If your VM deploy in **ARM** module, we can via new portal to Dissociate the public IP address.
 [image]

Also when we use Azure portal to create VM, we can select public ip address to **none**, in this way, the new VM will not create with a public IP:
[image]

If your VM create in ASM module, by default the VM create with a shared public IP address, and the Public IP address will NAT to other VMs in the same cloud service. We can't modify it now.